# iOS UIAutomation - reading the title of the navigationBar

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios-ui-automation, uiactivityviewcontroller

How do I check against the value of the title of the navigationBar in my app, using UIAutomation javascript? I've tried all sorts of things, like

> target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().title
>
> target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().name
>
> target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().value

And a few others, and none of them work.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out, it works with this:

> target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().name()

Comment: This is what worked for me too when referencing the cancel button in a UIActivityView text message window `target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().buttons()["Cancel"].tap();`

Answer (score 3):

You can access it by using the following script:

```cpp
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().navigationBar().staticTexts()[0].value()
```